# How to execute a function with a delay of a few seconds in Android programming

Tags: android, function, delay

I have two functions. The first function takes 8 seconds and the second function takes 5 seconds. I want the second function to run with a delay of 3 seconds and the program not to stop and the first function not to stop.
How can I do this?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Handler method :

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    yourfuction(); //This function will only work after 3 second
                }
            }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler handler =  new Handler();
        Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Things to be done
                       callYourFunction();
              handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);  //after every 3 sec call your function
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 3000);
```